# Citrix Netscaler 10.1 AAA Application Traffic Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on, netscaler, aaa

I have a Netscaler deployment with a virtual server where I have enabled authentication through the AAA Application Traffic feature. As Expected this allows my users to log on to the netscaler login prompt once and then have sso work for all applications behind the netscaler.

Via the Access Gateway we also have integrated Citrix giving our users a virtual non-personal desktop (xenapp?). In this desktop the users are allready logged in, and having to log in again when they open the website behind the VS with AAA is a major grief...

Is there a way to enable SSO for the AAA login page? So that users that are logged in to a system with a valid user, can be automatically logged in *ALSO* on the Citrix Netscaler login form?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to find a way to enable SSO for the Netscaler login-page, but we found a decent workaround which our customers accepted.

Since the virtual desktop users are on a different IP-segment, and we know that when they try accessing anything from that segment they already are logged in with a valid user, without exeption, we created a content switching policy that checks the source ip in the request. If they are from the guaranteed logged in segment, we skip the Netscaler login all together and send the user directly to the VS. All other users get the login from Netscaler.